# Insert a Javascript feature into a widget plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, widget

I'd like to insert the following javascript

```
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='pointer'; this.style.opacity=0.80"
```

in a widget plugin for wordpress, in order to make thumbnails color change on mouse hover...

The widget plugin is:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-random-posts-thumbnail-widget/

Where am I supposed to insert the code above in order to make it run correctly?

I made so many attempts, but it always returns with an error, deactivating the plugin.

Comment: You can easily have similar effect via css. No need to have JS. img:hover{cursor:pointer;opacity:0.8}

Comment: Awesome idea, thanks.
What if I want to limit this function, via css, to posts featured image only?
I mean the one I call this way: <?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'medium', true); echo $image_url[0]; ?>

Comment: Does the featured image have a consistent HTML ID or class across posts?

Comment: Not sure regarding what you exactly mean, but nope, shouldn't.

Comment: @DanielleFiorucci yes you can target to exact class only i.e. img.wp-post-image{you css here} , wp assign this class to almost any thumbnail if your theme is not stripping that class. Or you can add own class and then use that to target.

Comment: Tried this, but isn't working: img.wp-post-image:hover{opacity:0.8}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to apply opacity to images on mouse hover. You can have this simply applied via CSS.

That is in your stylesheet styles add. WordPress by default add wp-post-image class to thumbnails, so you can target using that class or you can add own custom class and target this style to that class:

```
img.wp-post-image:hover{cursor:pointer;opacity:0.8}
```

Comment: Can you share your theme's html code for thumbnail, i mean final html for the thumbnail part in view-source... so i see what class are being added to your thumbnail?

Comment: Which WP file is supposed to define this? style.css or mayb any other page?

Comment: Tried "a img:hover {opacity:0.8}" as well, but failed again :(

Comment: in your current active theme's style.css file

Comment: I think I've solved using a img:hover {opacity:0.8} ... Cloudflare was pissing me off even if set in development mode. Now looks working :D

Comment: @DanielleFiorucci well done! You may mark this answer as Solved.